# Bad user profile links in MOSS 2007 Site Usage Summary > Site users

Tags: sharepoint-2007

In the MOSS 2007 "Site collection users" page (... > Site Settings > Site Usage Summary > Site users), under the "User activity (past 30 days)" section there is a list of site users with their statistic (e.g. sharepoint\system). However, the link associated with each user points to a local server port URL (e.g. http://ssn1:23543/Person.aspx?accountname=sharepoint%5Csystem) which returns a 400 Bad Request or "User not found" error (depending on where the page is run).

How can I fix this to return a correct page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one after a Google search for "Person.aspx?accountname= user not found".

I believe our Shared Services provider is a little "unwell" after a MOSS SP2 upgrade and I needed to reconfigure the personal site provider and My Site settings in Central Administration.

The primary resource I followed was a Microsoft KB article at:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924399: *Error message when a user clicks the "My Profile" tab of a "My Site" personal site in SharePoint Server 2007: "Result: 404 File Not Found*

I also found these similar resources for confirmation:

- http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.sharepoint.portalserver&tid=5e135a25-d8fa-4ce9-b1d8-0940dd94b69e&p=1
- http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/09/15/754902.aspx

Following the Microsoft KB I created a new managed path for personal sites and created a new site collection in the correct web application. I then changed the Shared Services Provider (SSP) to point to the new site collection.

Of course the final step is also to import users into the new site collection (or migrate from an old location if necessary).